# What mean $0^d$ in this sequence from OEIS

Tags: sequences-and-series, oeis

From this [OEIS Sequence](https://oeis.org/A064222):

> $a(n+1) = (d+0^d)*10^{\lfloor{(log_{10}{a(n)+1))}}\rfloor} + (1-0^d)*\lfloor(a(n)/10)\rfloor$, where $d \equiv (a(n)+1) \,(mod \, 10)$

I want to know what that "$0^d$" means? Because when $d = 0$ we have a problem, and in rest of cases $0^d = 0$. Sorry if it is a stupid question but I don't understand. Thanks!

Comment: $0^0$ is defined as $1$ and if $d$ is below $0$ then there is a problem.

Comment: I don't know what OEIS means with that notation. But if it does mean exponentiation, then we don't have a problem with $d=0$. We have $0^0=1$.

Comment: It means exactly what you describe. I think intention is to have $d+0$ or $d+1$ in the term $(d+0^d)$, and $d+1$ should only appear when $10$ divides $d-a(n)-1$. Similarly the last summand with $(1-0^d)$ will be one, for most of the choices of $d$.

Comment: So $0^0 = 1 - \delta_{0d}$ in this case, when $d \geq 0$? ($\delta_{0d}$ = Kronecker Delta)

Comment: Also note that "mod" is used as a binary operator in this OEIS entry.  That is, we really do want
$$d = (a(n)+1) \operatorname{mod} 10$$
and **not**
$$d \equiv a(n)+1 \pmod{10}.$$ This means $d$ only takes values $0, 1, 2, \ldots, 9$ (in particular, since we're not talking about equivalence classes, it's not even possible for $d$ to be negative).

Comment: @MathLearner that should be $0^d=\delta_{0d}$

Comment: @Milten oh. Ok. I made a mistake! Thanks!